# Laravel 5.2 Route not working ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes

When calling a resource route, the server dies. Resulting in GET http://localhost:8000/tag net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Serving via php artisan serve on localhost:8000 on a *nix box.  Same results for ff and Chrome.

Ajax used is $.get

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::resource('business', 'BusinessesController');
    Route::resource('business.show', 'BusinessesController');
    Route::resource('business.create', 'BusinessesController');
    Route::resource('business.update', 'BusinessesController');

    Route::get('order', ['as' => 'order.default', 'uses' => 'BusinessesController@create']);
    Route::post('order', ['as' => 'order.post', 'uses' => 'BusinessesController@signUp']);

    Route::resource('tag', 'TagController');

});
Route::auth();
```

All routes work, with the exception of 'tag.'  Moreover, running php artisan route:list results in a segmentation fault.

The following works:

```
Route::get('tag', function(){
   $tags = App\Tag::get()->toArray();
   return $tags;

});
```

The controller:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Middleware\TagService;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Http\Requests;

class TagController extends Controller
{
    private $_ts;

    public function __construct(TagService $tagService)
    {
        $this->_ts = $tagService;
    }

    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        dd('test');
        return $this->_ts->get();
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

    }

   /**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

   /**
    * Update the specified resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Remove the specified resource from storage.
    *
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The request doesn't seem to make it to the controller.

Comment: Try to increase the `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` !

Comment: Are you sure `TagService` is working as expected? Usually when I hear about `artisan route:list` failing, it's something broken in the controller constructor (and all you seem to have there is some basic DI).

Comment: @tdhsmith, you're correct, it was the constructor.  Thanks.